# How to check the filter object is returning any data or not in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-filter

I have a model named Rooms. Now I want to check if a specific row exists in the model or not by this line of code:

```py
checkroom = Rooms.objects.filter(building_id=building_id, room_no=room_no).first()
```

If the row doesn't exist, then I want to print some text:
How Can I check the condition?

I have used

```py
if checkroom:
```

this condition to check if it exists. but now I want to check if it doesn't exist separately with an if condition.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#exists

Comment: What is not working with this? Normally this should work since it will return `None` if it can not find the record.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this :

```
if not checkroom:
    # Do this...
else:
    # Do that...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use exists query which is faster then retrieve a row.

```
is_exists_room = Rooms.objects.filter(building_id=building_id, room_no=room_no).exists()

if not is_exists_room:
    print("The room doesn't exist!")
```